# Executing project in terminal gives NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, eclipse, pdfbox

I got some code using the PDFBox. Executing it with Eclipse no Error. But when I try to use the Windows Terminal it shows:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/pdfbox/pdmodel/PDDocument
        at PdfReader2.main(PdfReader2.java:15)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument

Whats the problem?

Comment: Add required jars in classpath while executing.

Comment: What command do you execute on terminal?